# 「extension=/パス/hoge.so」と「zend_extension=/パス/hoge.so」の違い

Tags: php

**PHPエクステンションをphp.iniで追加する際、下記2種類あるように思うのですが、何が違うのでしょうか？**

```
extension=/パス/hoge.so

zend_extension=/パス/hoge.so
```

・PHPバージョン？
・それともエクステンション自体に、zend製とそれ以外があると言うことでしょうか？